# AudioRecord doesn't work for Motorola Milestone

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

I'm having this problem only on Motorola Milestone. Code:

```
// init recorder
recordInstance = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
    8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 8000);

recordInstance.startRecording();

//more code here

recordInstance.stop();
```

The errorinformation I have (can't find more for the moment since I don't have a milestone myself for debugging):

```
Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: stop() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.
at android.media.AudioRecord.stop(AudioRecord.java:51 6)
```

Apparantly I'm not the only one with this problem. Some very similar threads I found (without solution):

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/6dd24aeb484b2e40
http://web.archive.org/web/20100824043744/http://androidcommunity.com:80/forums/f2/problem-using-audiorecord-in-motorola-milestone-30935/
http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/Android-App-Development-for/Problem-using-AudioRecord-on-Milestone-device/m-p/3889
http://www.fring.com/forums/showthread.php?t=16194
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/63be273ba59c635e/1c4a010fd470d328

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
recordInstance = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
16000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 16000);
```

Just stick to the standard sample rates http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_rate#Audio. I wonder why Milestone does not support recording with 8bit encoding. This gives me an error too - "Invalid audio format".

Answer (score 0):

Firstly as it says try putting a try catch block over the stop, as the debugs message is saying, the recording is getting into an IllegalState.

Probably if u can catch the exception, you can find out what the problem is.

Comment: I did but couldn't get any more information than the reported java.lang.IllegalStateException with messages:

android startRecording called on an uninitialized AudioRecord

Comment: You can check the state using getState function so that u can atleast avoid a crash. This crash is because for some reason your recording is not initialised. Best done right after you have started and then throw an appropriate error message.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand I'll have to add some try catch but I was wondering if anyone knows what values for what devices work? As I believe these are vendor specific?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not parameters, the issue is a bug with Motorola's tinkering of Android, the AudioRecord will not create itself properly if the mode is IN_CALL, if its MODE_NORMAL it should be fine.

This is because something in Motorolas code hogs the input when its IN_CALL mode.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, the hcpl's code should work because the speech sampling is 8kHz but some android devices doesn't accept it.

Completing the mad answer, from the Android Developers website:

> sampleRateInHz    int: the sample rate expressed in Hertz. 44100Hz is
>   currently the only rate that is guaranteed to work on all devices, but
>   other rates such as 22050, 16000, and 11025 may work on some devices.
>   AudioFormat.SAMPLE_RATE_UNSPECIFIED means to use a route-dependent
>   value which is usually the sample rate of the source. getSampleRate()
>   can be used to retrieve the actual sample rate chosen.